# Why doesn't this boost::variant::operator= call compile?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, variant, boost-variant

Why doesn't `v = 42` compile here? It seems the compiler is trying to call the copy assignment operator of `Foo`, why? How can I get it to compile?

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct Foo {
    Foo(Foo&&) { }
};

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, Foo> v;
    v = 42;
}
```

[wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/elD03jcC2b7Df5SL)

The error message is:

```
In file included from prog.cc:1:
In file included from /usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant.hpp:17:
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:619:21: error: object of type 'Foo' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
        lhs_content = ::boost::detail::variant::move(*static_cast<T* >(rhs_storage_));
                    ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:112:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::variant::move_storage::internal_visit<Foo>' requested here
    return visitor.internal_visit(
                   ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:154:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl<boost::detail::variant::move_storage, void *, Foo>' requested here
    return (visitation_impl_invoke_impl)(
            ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:240:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke<boost::detail::variant::move_storage, void *, Foo, boost::variant<int, Foo>::has_fallback_type_>' requested here
        , BOOST_VARIANT_AUX_APPLY_VISITOR_STEP_CASE
          ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp:29:26: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_REPEAT'
# define BOOST_PP_REPEAT BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_, BOOST_PP_AUTO_REC(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_P, 4))
                         ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:22:32: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b)
                               ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp:29:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PP_CAT_I'
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b
                                 ^
<scratch space>:128:1: note: expanded from here
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1
^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2384:33: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<mpl_::int_<0>, boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<2>, int, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1>, Foo, boost::mpl::l_end> > >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end> >, boost::detail::variant::move_storage, void *, boost::variant<int, Foo>::has_fallback_type_>' requested here
        return detail::variant::visitation_impl(
                                ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2398:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, Foo>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<boost::detail::variant::move_storage, void *>' requested here
        return internal_apply_visitor_impl(
               ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2125:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, Foo>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::move_storage>' requested here
            this->internal_apply_visitor(visitor);
                  ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2171:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::variant<int, Foo>::variant_assign' requested here
            variant_assign( detail::variant::move(temp) );
            ^
/usr/local/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2189:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, Foo>::move_assign<int>' requested here
        move_assign( detail::variant::move(rhs) );
        ^
prog.cc:9:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::variant<int, Foo>::operator=<int>' requested here
    v = 42;
      ^
prog.cc:4:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'Foo' has a user-declared move constructor
    Foo(Foo&&) {}
    ^
```

Comment: How can I get it to compile? Add in a default assignment op `Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#idp1003193536-bb):

> Every bounded type must fulfill the requirements of the MoveAssignable concept.

And MoveAssignable requires move assignment (although this isn't spelled out anywhere in the documentation as far as I can find). `Foo` isn't move-assignable because the user-provided move constructor implicitly deletes the move-assignment operator. Hence, you don't meet the requirements for this operator.

---

This seems to be a QoI issue. There's no reason that `operator=(int )` should require `Foo::operator=(Foo )`. We can determine at compile-time which type will be the new engaged type (another one of the requirements), and that is the only one for which we would need to instantiate `operator=`. If the variant was initially `Foo`, we would simply want to destroy the original `Foo` and construct a new `int`.

Comment: You quoted the wrong part of the documentation. The right part is directly below. The move-assignment operator is picked, which only requires the contained types to be MoveAssignable.

Comment: @hvd Yep, fixed. Odd that Boost doesn't have a page for that.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems the compiler is trying to call the copy assignment operator of Foo, why?

That's just confusing wording. A move assignment operator (which you don't have either) would suffice.

As for why a move assignment operator is needed: `boost::variant`'s `operator=` is implemented in terms of assignment from another `boost::variant`. From your `int`, a `boost::variant<int, Foo>` is constructed. `v` is then move-assigned that `boost::variant<int, Foo>`. Which needs to account for the possibility that it's being move-assigned a `Foo`, even though that cannot happen.

You can see the `variant_assign` helper method responsible for this in your compiler's error message, and in [`variant.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/variant/variant.hpp):

```
template <typename T>
void move_assign(T&& rhs)
{
    // If direct T-to-T move assignment is not possible...
    detail::variant::direct_mover<T> direct_move(rhs);
    if (this->apply_visitor(direct_move) == false)
    {
        // ...then convert rhs to variant and assign:
        //
        // While potentially inefficient, the following construction of a
        // variant allows T as any type convertible to one of the bounded
        // types without excessive code redundancy.
        //
        variant temp( detail::variant::move(rhs) );
        variant_assign( detail::variant::move(temp) );
    }
}
```

While there's an optimisation there that allows the temporary variant to be skipped, that's only possible when the variant already contains an `int`, and regardless, it cannot be determined at compile time, so it wouldn't have prevented the instantiation of `variant_assign`.

Comment: "_it doesn't accept `int` directly_" — The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#idp1003177792-bb) say `operator=` should accept `int` here: `template<typename T> variant & operator=(const T & rhs);` and "T must be unambiguously convertible to one of the bounded types (i.e., T1, T2, etc.)."

Comment: @tuple_cat Right you are, I wrote a stronger claim than I had intended. Reworded, I'll double-check and try to back it up with sources.

Comment: "A move assignment operator is a copy assignment operator too"...wat?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get it reversed? A copy is a kind of move (that doesn't change the source).

Comment: @T.C. I haven't been able to find what I was thinking of when I wrote that. Whatever it was, it was unnecessarily confusing at best, probably just plain wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of the compiler warning is telling:

`prog.cc:4:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'Foo' has a user-declared move constructor`

The compiler will only generate implicitly declared constructors if no user-declared constructors of any kind are declared

Full description here [on Default Constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)

Can of course just tell it to generate this default assignment, but unclear of your actual code and if that'd be ok. Specifically, it's unclear why you have a custom move constructor.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct Foo {
    Foo(Foo&&) { }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
};

int main() {
    boost::variant<int, Foo> v;
    v = 42;
}
```